# about switch case in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function tool_line(action, x, y) {
    console.log(action);
    if (!mouseisdown) {
        return;
    }
    switch (action) {
        case "mousedown":
            startx = x;
            starty = y;
            break;
        case "mousemove":
            if (mouseisdown) {
                $(current_marker).remove();
                current_marker = svg_line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            }
            break;
        case "mouseup":
            console.log('why don't go there?');  // Question!
            svg_line(x1, x2, y1, y2);
            break;
    }
}
```

the console.log says

> mousedown
>    181 mousemove
>    mouseup

Like the code above, the action passed in actually goes well on the first two case, but even if the console says "mouseup", it still never pass the third case? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Take a look at the color of the code in the `mouseup` case block. Look a little funny it's all red? But why is there black text on the line above...

Comment: Because `mouseisdown` in false?

Comment: @JaredFarrish That’s most likely not in the actual code. It was added just for the question.

Comment: @Xufox - Of course, it wouldn't run at all.

Comment: @HBP you are right, There are some problem more than this. Thx

Comment: `console.log(action, ismousedown);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is because you are returning in when `mouseisdown` is false. Your code says that in the first case the mouse is down, that is why it gets hit. In the second case the mouse it has to be down to even execute pass the `if` statement. So you are moving the mouse while holding the left button.

Now the the third case `mouseup` can't meet the `mouseisdown` requirement. (I am pretty sure that flag is `false` when the action is `mouseup`) as it is the opposite, so your function gets returned before everything else gets executed, which makes the switch statement unreachable.

To test this just get rid of the first `if statement`, and check if you can hit `mouseup`. If you do, you have a logic related bug.